# Bootstrap column spacing inconsistent

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have columns on the home page of a website I am building, each containing an icon and text.  On mobile, however, the columns stack on top of each other and have inconsistent vertical spacing, due to the inconsistent length of the text.  Is there any way to force the columns to have consistent spacing in mobile view?

(If you run the below code snippet, press full page to see the spacing issue I am referring to)

```css
.info-blocks {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  /* background: #efefef; */
}

.info-blocks i.icon-info-blocks {
  float: left;
  color: #FFEB3B;
  font-size: 30px;
  min-width: 50px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #002e5b;
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  border: 1px solid #002e5b;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.info-blocks .info-blocks-in {
  padding: 0 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.info-blocks .info-blocks-in h3 {
  color: #002e5b;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 28px;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.info-blocks .info-blocks-in p {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.iconify.design/1/1.0.3/iconify.min.js"></script>

<br>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 info-blocks">
    <i class="icon-info-blocks"><span class="iconify" data-icon="mdi:map-legend" data-inline="false"></span></i>
    <div class="info-blocks-in">
      <h3>Explore</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 info-blocks">
    <i class="icon-info-blocks"><span class="iconify" data-icon="mdi:map-legend" data-inline="false"></span></i>
    <div class="info-blocks-in">
      <h3>Explore</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ut magna eleifend, fermentum arcu et, euismod neque. Sed ante elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 info-blocks">
    <i class="icon-info-blocks"><span class="iconify" data-icon="mdi:map-legend" data-inline="false"></span></i>
    <div class="info-blocks-in">
      <h3>Explore</h3>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: std?? why?? cant yu read like a regular guy???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a fixed height to `.info-blocks .info-blocks-in`
See snippet below (test it at different screen width):

```css
.info-blocks {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  /* background: #efefef; */
}

.info-blocks i.icon-info-blocks {
  float: left;
  color: #FFEB3B;
  font-size: 30px;
  min-width: 50px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #002e5b;
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  border: 1px solid #002e5b;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.info-blocks .info-blocks-in {
  padding: 0 10px;
  height:80px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.info-blocks .info-blocks-in h3 {
  color: #002e5b;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 28px;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.info-blocks .info-blocks-in p {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.iconify.design/1/1.0.3/iconify.min.js"></script>

<br>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 info-blocks">
    <i class="icon-info-blocks"><span class="iconify" data-icon="mdi:map-legend" data-inline="false"></span></i>
    <div class="info-blocks-in">
      <h3>Explore</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 info-blocks">
    <i class="icon-info-blocks"><span class="iconify" data-icon="mdi:map-legend" data-inline="false"></span></i>
    <div class="info-blocks-in">
      <h3>Explore</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ut magna eleifend, fermentum arcu et, euismod neque. Sed ante elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 info-blocks">
    <i class="icon-info-blocks"><span class="iconify" data-icon="mdi:map-legend" data-inline="false"></span></i>
    <div class="info-blocks-in">
      <h3>Explore</h3>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm not trying to get full width I'm referring to the vertical spacing

Comment: @MureyTasroc Thanks for clarifying that.  I've updated the snippet accordingly